# Iterating time series extraction of all bands in an Earth Engine weather data set using a feature collection of polygons and dates

Tags: python, google-earth-engine, time-series, google-earth-engine-python-api

I am trying to automate a time series extraction script I wrote in the GEE JavaScript API to run over a shapefile of polygons with start times and end times but am unsure on how to accomplish the iteration.

The original script

1. Takes a each image from a weather image collection,
2. Reduces each band value to the mean for the state of California, and
3. flattens the resulting image means into a table that can then be exported for analysis.

I have already uploaded the shapefile as a feature collection, but I am unsure of how to proceed. Ideally I would be able to use the Python API to do this, as that is where I am going to do my analysis, but I couldn't figure out how to do the time series extraction in the Python API.

As of right now, the only way I can accomplish my goal is to upload each polygon in the shape file individually and then manually input the parameters into my script. I hope there is a better way to do this.

The original script for the JavaScript API state-wide extraction can be found [here](https://code.earthengine.google.com/f89e12b1f98391be6c8e6ad41a966a2e?noload=true). The script exports a table of values to Google Drive

I attempted to convert the script to the Python API but I am unable to get the script to display the resulting table. Here is my attempt at the exporter using Python.

```
#Initialize EE
import ee
ee.Authenticate()
ee.Initialize()

#Set the start date and end date
start_date = '2017-10-08'
end_date = '2017-10-31'

start_date = ee.Date(start_date)
end_date = ee.Date(end_date)

#Grab image collection
gridmet_db = 'IDAHO_EPSCOR/GRIDMET'
gridmet_raw= ee.ImageCollection(gridmet_db)

#Load California Boundary from TIGER collection
cal_bounds = ee.FeatureCollection('TIGER/2016/States').filter(ee.Filter.Or(ee.Filter.eq('NAME','California')))
california = cal_bounds.geometry().bounds()

#Create the table
def return_triplet(image):

  def set_properties(f):
    return f.set('imageId',image.id()).set('system:index',image.get('system:index')).set('system:time_start',image.get('system:time_start'))

  return image.reduceRegions(    
    collection=california,
    reducer=ee.Reducer.mean(),
    scale=2500).map(set_properties).flatten()

def set_properties(f):
  return f.set('imageId',image.id()).set('system:index',image.get('system:index')).set('system:time_start',image.get('system:time_start'))

export_triplets_mean = gridmet_raw.filterDate(start_date,end_date).map(return_triplet)
```

The problem with the Python method is that the resulting table does not contain any of the band information and I am unsure of how to correct this.

```
{'type': 'FeatureCollection', 'columns': {}, 'id': 'IDAHO_EPSCOR/GRIDMET', 'version': 1585607718499608, 'properties': {'system:visualization_0_min': '290.0', 'type_name': 'ImageCollection', 'system:visualization_1_palette': ['d8d8d8', '4addff', '5affa3', 'f2ff89', 'ff725c'], 'thumb': 'https://mw1.google.com/ges/dd/images/IDAHO_EPSCOR_GRIDMET_thumb.png', 'description': '<p>The Gridded Surface Meteorological dataset provides\nhigh spatial resolution (~4-km) daily surface fields of temperature,\nprecipitation, winds, humidity and radiation across the contiguous\nUnited States from 1979. The dataset blends the high resolution\nspatial data from PRISM with the high temporal resolution data\nfrom the National Land Data Assimilation System (NLDAS) to produce\nspatially and temporally continuous fields that lend themselves\nto additional land surface modeling.</p><p>This dataset contains provisional products that are replaced with\nupdated versions when the complete source data become available.\nProducts can be distinguished by the value of the &#39;status&#39; property.\nAt first, assets are ingested with status=&#39;early&#39;. After several\ndays, they are replaced by assets with status=&#39;provisional&#39;.\nAfter about 2 months, they are replaced by the final assets with\nstatus=&#39;permanent&#39;.</p><p><b>Resolution</b><br>2.5 arc minutes\n</p><p><b>Cadence</b><br>\n  1 day\n</p><p><b>Bands</b><table class="eecat"><tr><th scope="col">Name</th><th scope="col">Units</th><th scope="col">Min</th><th scope="col">Max</th><th scope="col">Description</th></tr><tr><td>pr</td><td>mm, daily total</td><td>\n          0*\n</td><td>\n          690.44*\n</td><td><p>Precipitation amount</p></td></tr><tr><td>rmax</td><td>%</td><td>\n          1.05*\n</td><td>\n          100*\n</td><td><p>Maximum relative humidity</p></td></tr><tr><td>rmin</td><td>%</td><td>\n          0*\n</td><td>\n          100*\n</td><td><p>Minimum relative humidity</p></td></tr><tr><td>sph</td><td>kg/kg</td><td>\n          0*\n</td><td>\n          0.02*\n</td><td><p>Specific humididy</p></td></tr><tr><td>srad</td><td>W/m^2</td><td>\n          0*\n</td><td>\n          455.61*\n</td><td><p>Surface downward shortwave radiation</p></td></tr><tr><td>th</td><td>Degrees clockwise from North</td><td></td><td></td><td><p>Wind direction</p></td></tr><tr><td>tmmn</td><td>K</td><td>\n          225.54*\n</td><td>\n          314.88*\n</td><td><p>Minimum temperature</p></td></tr><tr><td>tmmx</td><td>K</td><td>\n          233.08*\n</td><td>\n          327.14*\n</td><td><p>Maximum temperature</p></td></tr><tr><td>vs</td><td>m/s</td><td>\n          0.14*\n</td><td>\n          29.13*\n</td><td><p>Wind velocity at 10m</p></td></tr><tr><td>erc</td><td>NFDRS fire danger index</td><td>\n          0*\n</td><td>\n          131.85*\n</td><td><p>Energy release component</p></td></tr><tr><td>eto</td><td>grass, mm</td><td>\n          0*\n</td><td>\n          17.27*\n</td><td><p>Daily reference evapotranspiration</p></td></tr><tr><td>bi</td><td>NFDRS fire danger index</td><td>\n          0*\n</td><td>\n          214.2*\n</td><td><p>Burning index</p></td></tr><tr><td>fm100</td><td>%</td><td>\n          0.28*\n</td><td>\n          33.2*\n</td><td><p>100-hour dead fuel moisture</p></td></tr><tr><td>fm1000</td><td>%</td><td>\n          0.36*\n</td><td>\n          47.52*\n</td><td><p>1000-hour dead fuel moisture</p></td></tr><tr><td>etr</td><td>Alfalfa, mm</td><td>\n          0*\n</td><td>\n          27.02*\n</td><td><p>Daily reference evapotranspiration</p></td></tr><tr><td>vpd</td><td>kPa</td><td>\n          0*\n</td><td>\n          9.83*\n</td><td><p>Mean vapor pressure deficit</p></td></tr></table>\n  * estimated min or max value\n<p><b>Image Properties</b><table class="eecat"><tr><th scope="col">Name</th><th scope="col">Type</th><th scope="col">Description</th></tr><tr><td>status</td><td>STRING</td><td><p>&#39;early&#39;, &#39;provisional&#39;, or &#39;permanent&#39;</p></td></tr></table><p><b>Terms of Use</b><br><p>This work (METDATA, by John Abatzoglou) is in the public domain and is free of known copyright restrictions. Users should properly cite the source used in the creation of any reports and publications resulting from the use of this dataset and note the date when the data was acquired.</p><p><b>Suggested citation(s)</b><ul><li><p>Abatzoglou J. T., Development of gridded surface meteorological data for ecological applications and modelling, International Journal of Climatology. (2012) doi: <a href="https://doi.org/10.1002/joc.3413">https://doi.org/10.1002/joc.3413</a></p></li></ul><style>\n  table.eecat {\n  border: 1px solid black;\n  border-collapse: collapse;\n  font-size: 13px;\n  }\n  table.eecat td, tr, th {\n  text-align: left; vertical-align: top;\n  border: 1px solid gray; padding: 3px;\n  }\n  td.nobreak { white-space: nowrap; }\n</style>', 'source_tags': ['idaho', 'uofi'], 'visualization_0_max': '314.0', 'title': 'GRIDMET: University of Idaho Gridded Surface Meteorological Dataset', 'product_tags': ['gridmet', 'metdata', 'temperature', 'humidity', 'radiation', 'precipitation', 'wind', 'climate', 'fireburning', 'nfdrs'], 'provider': 'University of Idaho', 'visualization_0_min': '290.0', 'system:visualization_1_bands': ['tmmx'], 'system:visualization_1_max': [314], 'visualization_0_name': 'Maximum Temperature', 'date_range': [283996800000, 1585267200000], 'period_mapping': [283996800000, 1585267200000], 'period': 1, 'system:visualization_0_bands': 'tmmx', 'provider_url': 'http://metdata.northwestknowledge.net/', 'sample': 'https://mw1.google.com/ges/dd/images/IDAHO_EPSCOR_GRIDMET_sample.png', 'system:visualization_1_name': 'Maximum Temperature', 'tags': ['idaho', 'uofi', 'gridmet', 'metdata', 'temperature', 'humidity', 'radiation', 'precipitation', 'wind', 'climate', 'fireburning', 'nfdrs'], 'system:visualization_0_max': '314.0', 'visualization_0_palette': 'd8d8d8,4addff,5affa3,f2ff89,ff725c', 'system:visualization_1_min': [290], 'system:visualization_0_palette': 'd8d8d8,4addff,5affa3,f2ff89,ff725c', 'system:visualization_0_name': 'Maximum Temperature', 'visualization_0_bands': 'tmmx'}, 'features': [{'type': 'FeatureCollection', 'columns': {}, 'properties': {'system:index': '20171008'}}, {'type': 'FeatureCollection', 'columns': {}, 'properties': {'system:index': '20171009'}}, {'type': 'FeatureCollection', 'columns': {}, 'properties': {'system:index': '20171010'}}, {'type': 'FeatureCollection', 'columns': {}, 'properties': {'system:index': '20171011'}}, {'type': 'FeatureCollection', 'columns': {}, 'properties': {'system:index': '20171012'}}, {'type': 'FeatureCollection', 'columns': {}, 'properties': {'system:index': '20171013'}}, {'type': 'FeatureCollection', 'columns': {}, 'properties': {'system:index': '20171014'}}, {'type': 'FeatureCollection', 'columns': {}, 'properties': {'system:index': '20171015'}}, {'type': 'FeatureCollection', 'columns': {}, 'properties': {'system:index': '20171016'}}, {'type': 'FeatureCollection', 'columns': {}, 'properties': {'system:index': '20171017'}}, {'type': 'FeatureCollection', 'columns': {}, 'properties': {'system:index': '20171018'}}, {'type': 'FeatureCollection', 'columns': {}, 'properties': {'system:index': '20171019'}}, {'type': 'FeatureCollection', 'columns': {}, 'properties': {'system:index': '20171020'}}, {'type': 'FeatureCollection', 'columns': {}, 'properties': {'system:index': '20171021'}}, {'type': 'FeatureCollection', 'columns': {}, 'properties': {'system:index': '20171022'}}, {'type': 'FeatureCollection', 'columns': {}, 'properties': {'system:index': '20171023'}}, {'type': 'FeatureCollection', 'columns': {}, 'properties': {'system:index': '20171024'}}, {'type': 'FeatureCollection', 'columns': {}, 'properties': {'system:index': '20171025'}}, {'type': 'FeatureCollection', 'columns': {}, 'properties': {'system:index': '20171026'}}, {'type': 'FeatureCollection', 'columns': {}, 'properties': {'system:index': '20171027'}}, {'type': 'FeatureCollection', 'columns': {}, 'properties': {'system:index': '20171028'}}, {'type': 'FeatureCollection', 'columns': {}, 'properties': {'system:index': '20171029'}}, {'type': 'FeatureCollection', 'columns': {}, 'properties': {'system:index': '20171030'}}]}
```

I'm looking for a Python solution to this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your `flatten()` call ended up on the wrong place when porting to Python. Try moving it from the `return_triplet()` function to where you've mapped over that function

```
export_triplets_mean = gridmet_raw.filterDate(start_date,end_date).map(return_triplet).flatten()
```

Here's the complete script:

```
#Initialize EE
import ee
ee.Authenticate()
ee.Initialize()

#Set the start date and end date
start_date = '2017-10-08'
end_date = '2017-10-31'

start_date = ee.Date(start_date)
end_date = ee.Date(end_date)

#Grab image collection
gridmet_db = 'IDAHO_EPSCOR/GRIDMET'
gridmet_raw= ee.ImageCollection(gridmet_db)

#Load California Boundary from TIGER collection
cal_bounds = ee.FeatureCollection('TIGER/2016/States').filter(ee.Filter.Or(ee.Filter.eq('NAME','California')))
california = cal_bounds.geometry().bounds()

#Create the table
def return_triplet(image):

    def set_properties(f):
        return f.set('imageId',image.id()).set('system:index',image.get('system:index')).set('system:time_start',image.get('system:time_start'))

    return image.reduceRegions(    
        collection=california,
        reducer=ee.Reducer.mean(),
        scale=2500).map(set_properties)

def set_properties(f):
    return f.set('imageId',image.id()).set('system:index',image.get('system:index')).set('system:time_start',image.get('system:time_start'))

export_triplets_mean = gridmet_raw.filterDate(start_date,end_date).map(return_triplet).flatten()
export_triplets_mean.aggregate_array('bi').getInfo()
```